# Ошибка requests в скрипте cgi на python

Tags: python-3.x, iis

Использую python 3.4

Методы библиотеки `requests` недоступны при запуске скрипта как `cgi`.

```
import requests
print("Content-type: text/html")
print("<h1> {}</h1>".format(dir(requests)))
```

Результат запуска под IIS:

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

при обращении к методам `post` или `get` ошибка (например requests.post)
выдает ошибку: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'post'`

Comment: А при обычном запуске скрипта что `print(dir(requests))` выдает?

Comment: При обычном запуске скрипта выдает все методы, включая post и get:   <h2> [,....'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'session'...и т.д]

Comment: Для других стандартных библиотек,например urllib3, ситуация аналогичная. При обычном запуске скрипта доступны все методы, а при запуске как cgi через IIS методы недоступны...

Comment: Тут больше с IIS проблема очевидно, чем с python :)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была из-за того, что стандартные библиотеки питон не были доступны при запуске скриптов под IIS 7 в режиме CGI. После добавления пути к библиотекам C:\python34\lib\site-packages в системную переменную PATH и рестарта Windows проблема была решена. Спасибо всем за участие.